# SVG in Jekyll not showing in browser, but code is

Tags: html, svg, jekyll

I'm including the following svg in my code

```
<svg width="40" height="40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill="#919191" d="m7.294075,23.110188l2.385864,0.023237l-0.083177,10.552679l15.878221,0l0,-10.514505l2.51405,0l0,13.07741l-20.707843,0l0.01289,-13.138815l-0.000005,-0.000006z"/>
  <rect fill="#919191" y="29.348862" x="11.184582" height="2.628626" width="12.437938"/>
  <rect fill="#a78b68" transform="matrix(0.5395733410304717,0.05172669848399204,-0.05207586478003252,0.5359555264108665,3.6611416648678325,1.4067255727666614) " y="41.524347" x="18.49125" height="5.003923" width="23.066864"/>
  <rect fill="#c19653" transform="matrix(0.5216998676238958,0.14625586092278992,-0.1472431193160242,0.5182018938275416,3.6611416648678325,1.4067255727666614) " y="27.438515" x="24.907076" height="5.003923" width="23.066864"/>
  <rect fill="#d48c28" transform="matrix(0.4640090244261216,0.2783830739288475,-0.2802622193151353,0.46089786509976993,3.6611416648678325,1.4067255727666614) " y="7.461092" x="30.089396" height="5.003923" width="23.066864"/>
  <rect fill="#fe8908" transform="matrix(0.3157222700143304,0.4376935608999602,-0.4406480862019664,0.31360536660688737,3.6611416648678325,1.4067255727666614) " y="-20.343803" x="28.488303" height="5.003923" width="23.066864"/>
  <rect fill="#ff7a15" transform="matrix(0.0893402304821676,0.5310828333843179,-0.5346677562821299,0.08874120831524585,3.6611416648678325,1.4067255727666614) " y="-47.045927" x="14.158203" height="5.003923" width="23.066864"/>
</svg>
```

I include this in my html partial here

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/2249869/userfriendly">
  <span class="icon icon--stackoverflow">
    {% include icon-stackoverflow.svg %} //this is the above svg
  </span>
  <span class="username">
   {{ include.username }}
  </span>
</a>
```

My footer

```
  <div class="footer-col footer-col-2">
    <ul class="social-media-list">
      {% if site.github_username %}
      <li>
        {% include icon-github.html username=site.github_username %}
      </li>
      {% endif %}

      {% if site.twitter_username %}
      <li>
        {% include icon-twitter.html username=site.twitter_username %}
      </li>
      {% endif %}

      {% if site.stackoverflow_username %}
      <li>
        {% include icon-stackoverflow.html username=site.stackoverflow_username %}
      </li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </div>
```

This is what is showing in my browser:

[image: I know the code is different than the beginning. I've tried multiple different SVG formats for the same thing.]

Note the lack of image. I know the code is different than the beginning. I've tried multiple different SVG formats for the same thing.

The same svg in codepen shows the desired results.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MadpgZ

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess that you have a CSS problem here. Any repository url to help debug ?

Comment: I've replicated your setup, and the SVG shows up normally, so the problem may be elsewhere. As David wrote above, if you have a link to a repo, we might be able to locate it.

Comment: Thank you for the help it is greatly appreciated. I will push to repo to github and share the link. But, I have no access until later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is pretty old, but I found it and I was having the same problem. I think I am even using the exact same jekyll theme (Gravity) because all your code looks the exact same.

The problem is that your SVG is 40 by 40 when it needs to be 16 by 16. When you resize the icon, the icon shows up automatically. It turns out resizing SVGs are a much bigger pain than I anticipated. Since jekyll inlines the SVG, it is hard to use CSS to scale the image. I ended up using inkscape to scale it. Here is the SVG scaled to the right amount.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="16"
   height="16"
   id="svg3512"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.91 r"
   sodipodi:docname="so.svg">
  <metadata
     id="metadata3532">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs3530" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="716"
     id="namedview3528"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="13.375"
     inkscape:cx="8.8971963"
     inkscape:cy="20"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="0"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg3512" />
  <path
     d="m 0.008293,9.3258921 1.5355776,0.011805 -0.053534,5.3604269 10.2194594,0 0,-5.3410357 1.61808,0 0,6.6429117 L 0,16 0.00829,9.3258965 l -3.2e-6,-3.1e-6 z"
     id="path3514"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     style="fill:#919191" />
  <rect
     y="12.494941"
     x="2.5122814"
     height="1.3352591"
     width="8.0052414"
     id="rect3516"
     style="fill:#919191" />
  <rect
     transform="matrix(0.9971499,0.07544586,-0.12218858,0.9925069,0,0)"
     y="9.8704548"
     x="3.9171355"
     height="1.3725955"
     width="8.0334988"
     id="rect3518"
     style="fill:#a78b68" />
  <rect
     transform="matrix(0.97638557,0.21603521,-0.33873527,0.94088172,0,0)"
     y="6.511641"
     x="5.775034"
     height="1.399946"
     width="7.9325705"
     id="rect3520"
     style="fill:#c19653" />
  <rect
     transform="matrix(0.90379955,0.42795605,-0.61032155,0.79215378,0,0)"
     y="1.6542813"
     x="6.9925656"
     height="1.4789127"
     width="7.6219997"
     id="rect3522"
     style="fill:#d48c28" />
  <rect
     transform="matrix(0.67463587,0.73815069,-0.87187447,0.48972943,0,0)"
     y="-6.0284266"
     x="5.8885627"
     height="1.627701"
     width="6.9478498"
     id="rect3524"
     style="fill:#fe8908" />
  <rect
     transform="matrix(0.20846184,0.9780305,-0.99152913,0.12988454,0,0)"
     y="-14.397026"
     x="1.9119557"
     height="1.7366618"
     width="6.3626075"
     id="rect3526"
     style="fill:#ff7a15" />
</svg>
```